# Xor thread and list of False

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to implement a variant of BitXor, that takes two lists of truth values as input and returns the list of element-wise Xor truth values as output.

```
MyXor = Thread[Xor[#, #2]] &;
```

It works fine, except when the inputs are the same. I expect to get

```
{False,False,False,False,False,False,...}
```

But I just get

```
False
```

Is there any way around this, without forcing the function to check for this case and reconstruct the list of False to output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Xor` always gives `False` when the to arguments are identical. One solution is to keep the `Xor` in `Thread` from evaluation

```
MyXor = Thread[Unevaluated[Xor[#, #2]]] &

l = RandomChoice[{True, False}, 10];
MyXor[l, l]
```